# Is there a mature way to interface Erlang and PostgreSQL or MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, erlang

I have searched the internet for drivers to connect to either database and all the projects I have seen have either been dead for a long time, look incomplete, or don't have good enough documentation to be usable without reading all the source.

Has anyone used Erlang to talk to either MySQL or PostgreSQL before and what sort of package did you use to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will Glozer wrote a nice native PostgreSQL client:

http://github.com/wg/epgsql

Answer (score 1):

Yariv's mysql driver seems to be the best available: http://code.google.com/p/erlang-mysql-driver/

http://yarivsblog.com/articles/2006/09/13/erlang-mysql-driver-reloaded/

I haven't personally used it as my erlang projects mostly talk to redis, but my quick scan of the source didn't reveal anything too terrifying.

Maturity is a relative thing, especially for more esoteric languages like erlang.

Comment: Dyzzyd also forked it and made some changes. http://github.com/dizzyd/erlang-mysql-driver
I know that Nick Gerakines used it somewhat for his facebook app "I Play WOW" that had quite a few users.

Answer (score 1):

[Erlang pgsql](http://frihjul.net/pgsql) - The pgsql-driver is a 100% erlang implementation of the Postgres Frontend/Backend protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Plain straight ODBC ? Quite simple to set it up, but a pain to make it work..

Answer (score 0):

http://github.com/inaka/sumo_db_mysql or http://github.com/inaka/sumo_db_pgsql Both of them are stable, actively maintained and used in production systems